# I need to access encrypted disk

Tags: linux-mint, data-recovery, disk, luks, live-usb

I'm trying to save all data from neighbors computer.

OS: Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon

I can't access disk because like on image is encrypted. I need to find a way to decrypt it or find a passphrase to copy all user data (mainly images).

I saw some kind of hashcat finding password but I don't know how to use it and what to type. Please help explaining step by step what should I do to save all data and broke passphrase.
[image]

Comment: If nobody knows the passphrase, it's not really possible, that's the point of encryption after all...

Comment: @frostschutz But every security have weakness ? Idk why they used this security but their must be some way. After all if no one will know answer then please could u tell me how to clear everything to prepare disk for new OS ?

Comment: @DARKVerbalCentaurPL "every security have weakness" is about as correct as "there's a nugget of gold in every bowl of soup": there's a weakness if something slipped by a really large group of security experts, and now you're hoping, as someone who has not done this for years before, that you'll find that nugget, even though none of them found it. There's probably no nugget in that soup, and you might not be the one with the metal detector.

Answer (score 3):

The answer here is simple: if you don't know the passphrase, you can't open the device. That is the point of (disk) encryption. There are some tools like [bruteforce-luks](https://github.com/glv2/bruteforce-luks) you can try to use to brute force the passphrase, but unless it is something like "1234" it will take (thousands) years to guess it.

LUKS also uses the [argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) key derivation function that makes it harder to brute force the passphrase on GPUs and even the "old" PBKDF makes guessing the passphrase significantly harder/slower by design.

Comment: Ok so I started using bruteforce-luks but how I can figure out what type after /dev/... . sda and sda1 is my USB live I guess but when I'm typing nvme0n1 or nvme0n1p(1,2,3,4,5,6) i getting msg: "Device /dev/..... don't exist or access denied". How I can figure out what type after /dev/ to start bruteforcing ?

Comment: The LUKS device is the LVM logical volume `/dev/vg_ssd256/lv_data`